# How to call method with arguments on another method in a Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

For example, if I have a method in my model that accepts a string from my controller. Am I able to call it elsewhere in my model, which would return the boolean value? Or is there a better way, possibly by setting a variable?

```
class Object
  def method_true?(args)
    ['a', 'b'].include?(args)
  end

  def do_stuff
    method_true? #outcome of method_true?
  end
end
```

Comment: The method should work fine provided you give the arguments right.

Comment: did you get it working?

Comment: Yeah, thanks! I did it a less hacky way and wrote this on in the controller (where it should've been in the first place) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Patching `Object` class is not the best idea.

More Rails way would be creating a module with these methods and mixing it into your models (or, into `ActiveRecord::Base`, if you are sure you need it everywhere):

```
module ActiveRecordExtentions
  def method_true?(args)
    ['a', 'b'].include?(args)
  end

  def do_stuff
    method_true? #outcome of method_true?
  end
end

# /initializers/activerecord_extentions.rb
ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, ActiveRecordExtentions) # or extend, you decide
```

Now methods are available in all models inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base`.